# React Material-UI: Elements rendered black in Safari and Microsoft Edge, Chrome working fine

Tags: reactjs, safari, material-ui, microsoft-edge

I'm building an app with React and I'm using Material-UI. On Chrome everything looks fine, but on Safari and Edge all elements are displayed as black. Below screenshots of the login page which just uses a few elements, but just happens to basically all of them. Overriding styles for every element is not a solution as that is ugly/not easy to do (especially with MUI input fields). Has anybody ever dealt with this?

[image: Chrome]

[image: Safari/Microsoft Edge]

Comment: Please include in your question the code necessary to reproduce this problem as well as a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) with that same code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Which version of Edge are you using? I checked the examples on [official site](https://material-ui.com/) in Edge and Chrome, the results are the same. Please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**, so that we can have a test and see how to help.